# Rscript does not support newline?

Tags: r, bash

I try to incorporate R script in bash script like

```
  #!/bin/bash
  ...some bash command
  Rscript -e 'a=1;
  print(a)';
```

but it complain

```
ARGUMENT 'print(a)' __ignored__
```

How to include newline in Rscript?

Comment: I would write my script  in a file and call it `Rscript myScript.R`.

Comment: I know, but i want to put it in bash

Comment: did you try using a continuation char at the end of each line, ie `-e a=1;\<CR>print(a)';`? Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also think the best approach would be to write a R script. With that in mind, you can create one in cache: just replace `-e 'code'` with `<(echo 'code')`:

```
Rscript <(echo 'a=1;
  print(a);')
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get what I think is the desired behavior with:

```
 Rscript -e 'print(123)' -e '
         print(234)'
```

So using the -e flag repeatedly and the second argument being incomplete by virtue of the leading single quote. Repeated lines are possible:

```
Rscript -e 'print(123)' -e '
print(234)' -e '
a=2222222' -e '
print(a)'
##------ 2013-02-11 ------##
[1] 123
[1] 234
[1] 2222222
```

Comment: MY GOD, hard to imagine how you come up with this god like solution. It works! But now I would rather write a single line.

Comment: You would probably be amused at the entire record of all the failed attempts I made before stumbling upon this. And that would not reflect the searching done on GMane.

Comment: The answer by flodel looks more decent and works too. But thank you any way